# Images not displaying in Postman

Tags: rest, express, postman, parse-server

I am trying to retrieve a image uploaded to `Parse-server` using the `REST-API` guide in `Postman` . When I upload the image there is a response  of successfully uploaded the image[image],  but when I use the response to retrieve it using `GET` request the image is not displayed instead a white small square is shown[image].

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: The white square simply indicates that the data you provided the File constructor was corrupt in some way. What code are you using to upload the picture?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I turned the interceptor OFF and that solved it.